# Troubleshooting Websockets with EC2 on AWS using Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I am using Django-Channels to try to get real time features such as chat/messaging, notifications, etc. Right now, I have gotten everything to work fine on my laptop using the settings described in the docs here: http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. I use a local redis server for testing purposes.

However, when I deploy to my Amazon EC2 Elastic Beanstalk server (using an AWS ElastiCache Redis), the WebSocket functionality fails. I was reading and I think it is due to the fact that Amazon's HTTPS does not support WebSockets, so I need to switch to Secure TCP.
I tried doing that with:
https://blog.jverkamp.com/2015/07/20/configuring-websockets-behind-an-aws-elb/
and
https://medium.com/@Philmod/load-balancing-websockets-on-ec2-1da94584a5e9#.ak2jh5h0q
but to no avail.

Does anyone have any success implementing  WebSockets with CentOS/Apache and Django on AWS EB? The Django-Channels package is fairly new so I was wondernig if anyone has experienced and/or overcome this hurdle.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm also attempting to use EBS. As far as I can tell, the default Python container expects to use WSGI (hence `WSGIPath: "appname/wsgi.py"` in `"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python"`) and therefore makes it difficult to run Daphne instead. Did you ever find a way to resolve this?

Comment: Did u figure this out??

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-implement-Server-Push-in-Django-without-using-third-party-services#gmKROc

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Are you using Load Balancer?

Comment: @error2007s yes i am, how come? i am using elastic beanstalk service for the web app if that clarifies anything.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has launched new Application Load Balancer that supports web sockets. Change your ELB to Application Load Balancer and that will fix your issue.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://blog.mangoforbreakfast.com/2017/02/13/django-channels-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-an-alb/) it's possible to run Django Channels on Elastic Beanstalk using an Application Load Balancer.

In a simplified form, it's basically:

1. Create an ALB
2. Add 2 target groups, one that points to port 80, and one that points to Daphne port, ie 8080.
3. Create 2 *path rules*. Let the default route point to target group 1 (port 80), and set the second to use a relative path, ie. **/ws/** and point it to target group 2.
4. Add Daphne and workers to supervisord (or another init system)
5. DONE! Access Daphne/websockets through the relative url *ws://example.com/ws/*.

Comment: I tried this one @ege, but I'm still getting `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose ALB is the only way. The reason is because with the SSL protocol listner in the classic LB, the session stickiness and X-Forwaded headers won't be forwarded and will result in the proxy server redirect loop. Doc is here,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html

I'll update the answer if I find out a way with the existing CLB.